# Conditional urn balls without replacement

Tags: probability

> An urn contains $w$ white and $b$ black balls. $n$ extractions without replacement are made. What is the conditional probability of drawing white on $8$th draw and blank on $5$th draw given that a white on $1$st and $7$th draw?

I need to find:

$$\Pr(W_{8}B_{5}|W_{1}W_{7})=\frac{\Pr({W_{8}B_{5}}\cap {W_{1}W_{7}})}{\Pr({W_{1}W_{7}})}$$

By the symmetry of extraction $W_7=W_2$, $W_8=W_3$ and $B_5=B_4$ so

$${\Pr({W_{1}W_{7}})}={\Pr({W_{1}W_{2}})}=\frac{w}{w+b}\frac{w-1}{w+b-1}$$ and 
$$\Pr({W_{8}B_{5}}\cap {W_{1}W_{7}}) = \Pr({W_{3}B_{4}}\cap {W_{1}W_{2}}) = \frac{w-2}{w+b-2}\frac{b}{w+b-3}\frac{w}{w+b}\frac{w-1}{w+b-1}$$

Am i correct?

Comment: The calculation is right. The explanation, in particular the assertion that $W_7=W_2$, is imprecise. You could also compute the conditional probability directly.  Given that we have white on $1$ and $7$, there are only $w-2$ white around, and a total of $w+b-2$ balls.

Answer (score 1):

As André remarked in a comment, the probability is more directly determined by noting that whites on the first and seventh draws leave $w-2$ white balls and $b$ black balls, $w+b-2$ balls in total, so under this condition the probability of drawing one white and one black in a given order is

$$
\frac{(w-2)b}{(w+b-2)(w+b-3)}\;.
$$